# How can i solve cant find module: "sass" error?

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages, parcel

I'm new to react and decided to try another method to start a project instead of create-react-app which i regret, I used a site createapp.dev which uses a parcel bundler instead of react-scripts bundler so after i was done with the project i tried deploying it to github pages but could not i've read the parcel documentation but still no help so i restarted the project with create-react-app  then copied the code but now i'm swimming in a bunch of errors [image: image error message]

Answer (score 3):

1.Install missed packages 
if you use:

1.npm : `npm install --save react-router-dom sass-loader sass` 
2. yarn : `yarn add react-router-dom sass-loader sass`

Answer (score 0):

Try with npm: `npm install --save-exact sass@1.51.0`
Then open package.json file and check, here I'm using this version and it's still working now.